# Changing the template data not refreshing the elements

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have searched and tried suggestions mentioned in various posts but no luck so far.
Here is my issue.
I have created a custom element `<month-view id="month-view-element"></month-view>` in my mainpage.html. Inside mainpage.html when this page is initially loaded i created a empty json object for all the 30days of a month and print a placeholder type cards in UI. Using the code below.

```
var json = [];
for(var x = 0; x < total; x++) {
    json.push({'hours': 0, 'day': x+1, 'year': year});
}
  monthView.month = json; //Doing this line. Prints out the desired empty cards for me in the UI.
```

created a month-view.html something like below:

```
    <dom-module id='month-view'>
<template>
<template is="dom-repeat" items= "{{month}}">

<paper-card class="day-paper-card" heading={{item.day}}>
  <div class="card-content work">{{item.work}}</div>
  <div class="card-actions containerDay layout horizontal">
    <div style="display:inline-block" class="icon">
                <paper-icon-button icon="icons:done" data-hours = "8"  data-day$="{{item.day}}" data-month$={{item.month}} data-year$={{item.year}} on-click="updateWorkHours"></paper-icon-button>
                <paper-tooltip>Full day</paper-tooltip>
    </div>
  </div>
</paper-card>
</template>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "month-view",
        updateWorkHours: function (e, detail) {
            console.log(e);
            this.fire('updateWorkHour', {day: e.target.dataHost.dataset.day, 
                                         month: e.target.dataHost.dataset.month,
                                         year: e.target.dataHost.dataset.year,
                                         hours: e.target.dataHost.dataset.work
                                         });

        }
    });
</script>

</dom-module>
```

There is another file script.js which contains the function document.addEventListener('updateWorkHour', function (e) { // doStuff });. I use this function to make a call to a google client API. I created a client request and then do request.execute(handleCallback);
Once this call is passed i landed in handleCallback function. In this function i do some processing of the response data and save parts of data into json variable available in the file already. And once all processing is done i did something like below.

```
 monthView.month = json;
```

But this above line is not refreshing my UI with the latest data. Is there anything I am missing? Any suggestions or anything i am doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'set' or 'notifyPath' while changing Polymer Object or Arrays in javascript for the databinding/obserers to work. You can read more about it in https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#path-binding

In your case try below code

```
monthView.set('month',json);
```

Updated suggestions:

Wrap your script on main page with. This is required for non-chrome browsers.

```
addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {})
```

This could be scoping issue. Try executing 'document.querySelector('#month-view-element');' inside your callback addWorkHoursCallBack. Also, Use .notifyPath instead of .set.

Comment: I tried monthView.set('month', json); as well. But its not reflecting the new data. I tried console.log(json) before the above line and find the json is correctly updated as i needed. But monthView.set('month', json2) has no effect.

Comment: @Srikanth a jsbin would be helpful to see what's happening in your code.

Comment: I have my code in multiple files, so not sure how I created in a jsbin. But i will try copying most of my code into it and will share in a bit. Thanks for checking.

Comment: You can use this plunker as the base if it helps http://plnkr.co/edit/13QJ7QFETIBg4bEiCMS7?p=info

Comment: Oops! Din't see your previous comment. I created 3 files. Below are the link https://jsbin.com/nujutonena/edit?html https://jsbin.com/kihamuyefe/edit?html,output https://jsbin.com/taroxanozo/edit?html,output I will try plnkr as well now.

Comment: I have loaded into Plunker. But not seeing any output., http://plnkr.co/edit/13QJ7QFETIBg4bEiCMS7?p=preview

Comment: The link you have provided is the plunker I have provided. Can you please provide your plunker.

Comment: I see., i have no idea on Plunker., Try this link http://plnkr.co/edit/CJrCEpk76cOMuzQstkTu?p=preview

Comment: I have provided some more suggestion. I cannot do further verification as the call back does not run without defining shortner.

Comment: Where is the suggestion can you paste here. I can't find in the document.

Comment: I have updated the post. Sorry, could have been more clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92914/discussion-between-srikanth-and-srik).